# Pgagent and Postgis are not seen in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin, rails-postgresql

I have a rail project and I tried to add checkin property to my app.

I have already install Postgis and pgAgent tool to my Postgres server from ApplicationStackBuilder but I can not find these tools in my pgAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgis is an extension, after you install it you need to add it to your database.

[image]

PgAgent add a new tree so you create jobs (`Trabajos`)

[image]

Make sure pgAgent service is started

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @JuanCarlosOropeza :)